# Interpreting Treatment Effects from R Logistic Regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, treatment-effect

This is probably a simple(ish) question but I would appreciate any help/pointers.

I have the following logistic regression model:

```
mod <- d[, glm(accepted ~ has_degree + is_resident + age, family=binomial)]
```

Where the outcome variable is binary (0 for not accepted, 1 for accepted). The model produces the following results (via summary(mod))

```
    Call: glm(formula = accepted ~ has_degree + is_resident + age,
    family=binomial)

    Deviance Residuals: 
    Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
    -2.11364  -0.07556   0.24139   0.59416   1.87022  

    Coefficients:
                Estimate    Std.Error   z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept) -228.9320    81.6951   -2.802  0.00507 ** 
    has_degree  -1.1979      0.5766    -2.078  0.03774 *  
    is_resident -1.0126      1.1522    -0.879  0.37946    
    age          2.3549      0.8388     2.807  0.00499 **
    --- 
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 112.467  on 99  degrees of freedom
    Residual deviance:  75.987  on 96  degrees of freedom
    AIC: 83.987

    Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

How can I determine the treatment effects explained by the model? If I take the sum all e^predictor variable estimates will this provide the treatment (ratio from 0 to 1) explained by the model?

Comment: Spend a significant time studying the basics of logistic models.  You'll see that taking logs of things that are already logged is not the way to go.  But start with general principles.  Doing that will expose you to how to state and test any contrast of interest.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for when you say "*treatment effects explained by the model*".   ...  You can get the ***predicted values*** from the model.  ...  Or maybe you want to use something like *emmeans* to compare the predicted values for levels of an independent variable ?

Comment: @SalMangiafico I could have done a better job with question  language. Essentially what I am interested in is quantifying what percentage of my binary outcome variable (accepted) is accounted for or explained by the model above.  Piggybacking on Franks comment, I assumed I could just take e^estimate for each covariate and add those up?  This would be a value bound between 0,1.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Sorry I realize my goof right after I posted.

Comment: You might look at some of the predictive performance measures in https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue